# Flask-Bootstrap custom theme

Tags: css, flask

I made a flask app with flask-bootstrap. I am using virtualenv as well. Where would I find the stylesheet that I edit to customize the colors? Or is there another way to have custom colors?

Comment: You'll need to add a stylesheet in your template.

Answer (score 12):

Add you custom colors to a css file, e.g. `mystyle.css`, put it under the static folder, then add your custom css file to your template.

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='mystyle.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```

Check the documentation here: [Adding a custom CSS file:](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#examples)