# Adjust bootstrap within jinja template (Flask Framework)

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-bootstrap

I would like to adjust default bootstrap class formatting within jinja template. The only thing, what I want to do, is to change the color of the h1 element. But unfortunately, it is still black.

I am using `flask` and `render_template` module.

I have following code in template:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_adjust.css">

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello, Vaclav!</h1>
     </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

boostrap_adjust.css looks like this:

```
h1{
    color:blue;
}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Vaclav

Comment: A trick, if that's the only thing you want to change, is `<h1 style="color:blue;">Hello, Vaclav!</h1>`

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment. That is how I solved that for now, but I would like to learn how to adjust that with external css.

Comment: Give an id to `h1` element. Then change the color using that id. That way you will override default settings of bootstrap. Also you could use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found working solution here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664156/flask-bootstrap-custom-theme
```

So in my case this works:

```
{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap_adjust.css')}}">

{% endblock %}
```

.css file is placed in the folder static. But be careful, static is not part of the path in `filename` parameter, because `url_for('static')` looks automatically in this folder.

Thank you all for your willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

I ll try to answer the question "how to adjust an element using a .css file instead of styling it directly?"

Go in your `base.html` file, i.e. the file you extend from, and in the header tag, at the end of all the other stylesheets create a Jinja2 block like so

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

Second step would be to call this block in your child templates and pass your .css files in there instead of passing it in the head block.

```
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_adjust.css">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

Give it a try and let us know!

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your advice. I tried that exactly as you wrote, but it doesn't work unfortunately. 
I just found this thread and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664156/flask-bootstrap-custom-theme

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom CSS file:

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="{{url_for('.static', filename='mystyle.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```

Please Read the documentation on Flask-Bootstrap and have a good understanding of super classes.

This is the Link - [Flask-Bootstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#templates)

Comment: The last update of Flask-Bootstrap was in 2019.